# Instantiating an activity object, what consequences for performance and memory?

Tags: android

Suppose I have an activity MyMainActivity, let's say complex enough with a bunch of code.

From another activity, to access a public variable or a method I instanciate :

```
MyMainActivity ma = new MyMainActivity();
ma.editVariableMethod();
String example_variable = ma.public_examplevariable;
```

When I instanciate MyMainActivity ma, is it like creating the hole activity again and storing everything from MyMainActivity to memory, and that way it takes the same amount of memory it would take if I was starting MyMainActivity, or is it just a link which permits to edit variables from MyMainActivity?

Comment: Why would you instantiate the activity by yourself? Why can't Android take care of that?

Comment: NEVER attempt to instantiate an `Activity` using `new` - it's not how the Android `Activity` class is designed to be used...end of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad practice to share memory-resident objects between objects in Android, no matter what the objects are. Android won't ensure that it will work. There are alternatives available for most use cases. In the particular case of "accessing a public variable" in another Activity, you can call startActivityForResult(), or ensure that your Activities store data they want to "share" in SharedPreferences, etc.
If you have two or more Activities that use the same method, you should first consider if the class needs to be abstracted into a separate object. Ideally, Activities should be frameworks that delegate to POJOs.

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate an Activity. The framework has to take care of it. If you want to use public methods either make them static OR get a reference to a valid instance of the activity object.

Edit:

As Squonk pointed out, depending on your use case, it might be a better idea to just extract the shared logic to another new class, at least until you know what you're doing. Giving "full access" to internal variables or even methods in an Activity might seem to work, but it's *very likely* NOT the right approach.

Comment: An `Activity` shouldn't have any `public` and/or `static` fields or methods to be accessed from any other application component.

Comment: Errr, s/he said "from another activity".

Comment: @Squonk why not? You can have your own activity which extends the original one and add some methods in it... I think it's not so _evil_. I would say it's a common practice

Comment: But also, a good use case is to implement an interface so that a Fragment can notify the owner activity of an event. In that case those methods would have to be public. Well, I guess *technically* they could be protected heh.

Comment: @dmon : **"from another activity"** - OK, describe to me how that would work. I've answered questions like this dozens of time usually as a result of somebody trying to do it and finding their code crashes and burns. If you need to use 'shared code' in Android, an `Activity` isn't the repository to do it - a helper class or even a class which extends `Application` but due to the life-cycle of the `Activity` class, attempting to 'share' code or data between different `Activities` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: That's indeed a good point. If the end goal is arbitrary non-activity related code reuse, using an Activity is definitely not ideal (or desirable). Which might be what the OP is asking, but who knows.

Comment: @Tomas : Why would a class which extends a class which extends `Activity` only be able to access `public` fields/data in its sub-class? Besides, my point is trying to do this stuff between two separate `Activity` classes or worse (as I've seen on SO recently) a `Service` trying to access `public static` UI widgets in an `Activity`.

Comment: Yeah I think I saw that Service/Activity question too.

Comment: I wanted to do that because dealing with Intents is a pain and unefficient, can conduct to a bunch of unpredicted bugs, and my static variables are are making my activity leak memory. I wondered if it was possible that way.

Comment: Sounds like you should create a utility class that helps you deal with the intents then. That way you can call it from any Activity when you need it.